# Form button not working on mobile (working fine on desktop) reactjs

Tags: reactjs

react nodejs express project need help button works on desktop but not on mobile

```
function SignIn() {

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/SignIn', { email, password }) 
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result.data)
                console.log(result)
                if (result.data === "success") { 
                    navigate('/Home');
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setError(<p id='error'><strong></strong>{err.response.data } !</p>);    });
    };

    return (
                
                
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <MDBInput wrapperClass='mb-4' label='Email' id='form3' type='email' value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                                <MDBInput wrapperClass='mb-4' label='Password' id='form4' type='password' value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                                {error}

                                <div className='d-flex justify-content-center mb-4'>
                                    <MDBCheckbox name='flexCheck' value='' id='flexCheckDefault' label='Keep me signed in' />
                                </div>
                                <button type='submit' />Sign in</button>
                            </form>
```

[text](https://04a5-197-15-84-56.ngrok-free.app)
"test it "
i ried botstrap button also didn't work
removed alot of code because of stackoverflow didn't allow

here is complete code [text](https://codeshare.io/8XJzyv)

Answer (score 0):

If your button have `type="submit"`, you don't need pass the `handleSubmit` method to prop `onClick` of the button. Becase this method already will be called anyway.

The way you are doing it, the method will be called twice.

Comment: yeah i know i was just testing already in comment